# How to run multiple versions of emacs for package development?

Tags: version-compatibilty

Is there a set of tools to enable testing a package on multiple Emacs versions.
For example 24.4 is almost released. Can I install it and still safely test my package in 24.1?

- How would I deal with a conflicting .emacs.d/?

I came across a [repo](https://github.com/Bruce-Connor/names#version-compatibility) on Github that says

> Currently, Names is being supported on the entire Emacs 24 family (24.1–24.4)

And realized I have no idea how to accomplish testing cleanly on multiple Emacs versions.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There is a good collection of tools for Emacs Lisp testing:

- [evm](https://github.com/rejeep/evm) - Emacs Version Manager.
- [Cask](https://github.com/cask/cask) - project management tool for Emacs that helps automate the package development cycle; development, dependencies, testing, building, packaging and more.
- [ert-runner](https://github.com/rejeep/ert-runner.el) - tool for Emacs projects tested using Ert.
- [ecukes](https://github.com/ecukes/ecukes) - testing framework for integration testing.
- [Travis CI](https://travis-ci.org/) - continuous integration service.
- [undercover.el](https://github.com/sviridov/undercover.el) - test coverage library for Emacs Lisp.

There is also a lot of useful information about Emacs Lisp testing at Johan Andersson's [blog](http://tuxicity.se/).

Comment: There is really a lot of useful info in your answer, evm looks great, and for testing I was unaware of undercover.el and Johan Andersson's blog. Thank you.