# Can I run two different builds of the same Emacs version?

Tags: build

My Linux distribution ships out Emacs version 28.2, with a particular build configuration, and I currently use that.

However, it was not compiled with `xwidget` support, and so I want to build 28.2 from source.

I've already done this for Emacs 27.2, and I can alternatively run `emacs`, which is the system installation of version 28.2, or `emacs-27.2`, which is the version I built from source. (I mostly run the latter with the `-Q` option, to test out issues with packages.)

If I build 28.2 from source with the `xwidget` flag, will I be able to keep and use the distro-shipped build as well? I.e. the new build is identified via `emacs-28.2` rather than just `emacs`.

And if I can get two separate instances of 28.2 on my system, will they not recognize the other's byte-compiled packages (see [this question](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/13250/how-do-i-run-multiple-versions-of-emacs-with-the-same-emacs-d)), the same way *different* versions (e.g. 27.2 and 28.2) have incompatible byte-compilations?

Comment: Generally speaking, your distro's Emacs will be installed in `/usr/bin` and there will be both an `emacs-28.2` and a symlink to it under the name `emacs`. When you build it yourself and do `make install`, you will get the same thing but in `/usr/local/bin` by default. So if you do nothing else, both `emacs` and `emacs-28.2` will get you whichever version is found first in your PATH. I would recommend that you disambiguate it by renaming your executable (and the symlink) in `/usr/local/bin` to something more distinctive. N.B. Different distros can and do things differently so YMMV.

Comment: As for the byte-compilation question, there should be no difference: `xwidget` support will not affect how the byte compiler works, so byte-compiled packages will work the same way with both versions.

Comment: @NickD Thanks -- in my system, it looks like everything gets installed to `/usr/bin`; there's nothing of the form `emacs*` in `/usr/local/bin`. Is there any way to rename the executable binary to something like `emacs-28.2-xwidgets` (or any other name) when building it? I guess I can use the prefix option and do `--prefix=$HOME/emacs-xwidgets/`, rename the resulting binary, and put a link to it in my PATH.

Comment: The top-level Makefile in the Emacs repo defines `prefix=/usr/local`, so you (or somebody...) must have done something (perhaps `./configure --prefix=/usr` ?) to change that. For the renaming, you can modify the Makefile but it can be easily done by a three-line script after installation: `mv /usr/local/bin/emacs-28.2 /usr/local/bin/emacs-28.2-xwidgets; ln -s /usr/local/bin/emacs-28.2-xwidgets /usr/local/bin/emacs-xwidgets; rm /usr/local/bin/emacs`.

Comment: @NickD You're probably right about the previous build install, it was a while back now and I didn't document it unfortunately. I think I did change the default location because the libraries for 27.2 would be installed to `/usr/lib/emacs/27.2`, which already had a directory for 28.2 -- there's no such Emacs directory on my system in `/usr/local/lib`.

Comment: Thanks for the advice on the post-install script, but re:my previous point, the new build would look for `/usr/local/lib/emacs/28.2` for the library files, right? Renaming or moving the directory wouldn't help. I guess that way it doesn't conflict with my existing install.